# Using azure function output parameters with Dropbox connector

Tags: azure, dropbox, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

My flow is very simple: I want to have an azure function that runs once a day and they use its output to create a file in Dropbox.

The function does some processing and returns an object with 2 properties, a FileName and a FileContent, both are strings.:

```
return new AzureFunctionResponse
{
    FileName = $"TestFile-{DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds()}",
    FileContent = "This is the file content"
};
```

My problem is that I don't know how to use those 2 properties to setup my Dropbox connector

Here's my LogicApp flow:

[image]

**I'd like to use the FileName and FileContent returned from my AzureFunction to populate the respective field in the Dropbox connector** but I have no idea how to set this up. I've looked for documentation, but maybe I'm not looking at the right place because I'm not finding anything.

Also here are the bindings in my function.json file, if that can be of any help.

```
{
  "disabled": false,
  "bindings": [
  {
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "webHookType": "genericJson",
      "name": "req"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Parse JSON action after the function should do exactly what you need. Will parse output and make them available for you in the next step.

Comment: Thanks jeff, I literally just figured it out. Works well!

Comment: If wanting to go the advanced route, you call also parse the results directly with the workflow expression language. @body('nameOfAction')['propertyName'] -- so in your case it would be @body('Azure_Function')['FileName']

Answer (score 1):

As alternative, you can implement the whole thing without using Logic Apps.

Make an Azure Function with Timer input trigger and Api Hub File output binding. No HTTP bindings are needed.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43348985/dynamic-output-file-name-of-apihubfile-azure-function-binding-one-drive-drop-b) for an example.