# Dynamic output file name of ApiHubFile Azure Function binding (one drive, drop box etc)

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function with Timer Trigger, and then I want to generate a file with dynamic (defined in runtime) name and contents and save it to e.g. OneDrive.

My function code:

```
public static void Run(TimerInfo myTimer, out string filename, out string content)
{
    filename = $"{DateTime.Now}.txt";
    content = $"Generated at {DateTime.Now} by Azure Functions";    
}
```

And `function.json`:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myTimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 */5 * * * *"
    },
    {
      "type": "apiHubFile",
      "name": "content",
      "path": "{filename}",
      "connection": "onedrive_ONEDRIVE",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

This fails though, with

```
Error indexing method 'Functions.TimerTriggerCSharp1'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: 
Cannot bind parameter 'filename' to type String&. Make sure the parameter Type 
is supported by the binding. If you're using binding extensions 
(e.g. ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method 
for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. config.UseServiceBus(), 
config.UseTimers(), etc.).
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how you could do it:

```
#r "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ApiHub"

using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Bindings.Runtime;

public static async Task Run(TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log, Binder binder)
{
    log.Info($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");    

    var fileName = "mypath/" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh-mm-ss") + ".txt";

    var attributes = new Attribute[]
    {    
        new ApiHubFileAttribute("onedrive_ONEDRIVE", fileName, FileAccess.Write)
    };


    var writer = await binder.BindAsync<TextWriter>(attributes);
    var content = $"Generated at {DateTime.Now} by Azure Functions"; 

    writer.Write(content);
}
```

And the `function.json` file:

```
    {
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myTimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "10 * * * * *"
    },
    {
      "type": "apiHubFile",
      "name": "outputFile",
      "connection": "onedrive_ONEDRIVE",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

You shouldn't really need the `apiHubFile` declaration in your `function.json` but because of a bug I noticed today it should still be there. we will fix that bug.

Comment: Thanks. Any plans to make declarative approach work? Or is it not feasible?

Comment: No because you will need imperative binding. you are generating the file name and its content at runtime during the function execution.

Comment: Yes, but same is true when I generate file contents at runtime, an still I'm able to declaratively bind it. But ok, I got your point :)

Comment: Yes I meant the file name :-) btw the bug I found while replying to this post is fixed and will be available soon. here is the PR if interested: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/pull/210

Answer (score 3):

To have full control over the name and path of an output during function execution, you need to use [imperative binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings#advanced-binding-at-runtime-imperative-binding)

For example: function.json

```
{
      "type": "blob",
      "name": "outputBinder",
      "path": "export/test",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
      "direction": "out"
},
```

Function:

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log, IBinder outputBinder)
{
     var attribute new BlobAttribute($"{some dynamic path}/{some dynamic filename}", FileAccess.Write);
     using (var stream = await outputBinder.BindAsync<Stream>(attribute))
     {
          // do whatever you want with this stream here...
     }
}
```

Comment: The question is not about blob storage, but I guess the technique is similar

Comment: does all of this Azure function stuff apply to the WebJobs SDK as well?