# Azure Function with PowerShell, Storage Queue trigger, and OneDrive for Business

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm trying to create an Azure Function that executes PowerShell with a Storage Queue trigger. For testing purposes, I want this function to manipulate a file in my OneDrive for Business account. To copy the file at `aapdftoimage/ThreePages.pdf` to `aapdftoimage/output_ThreePages.pdf`.

When OneDrive for Business is integrated as an Input, I get errors any time the function is triggered by a new message in the queue. If I disconnect OneDrive as input I don't get any errors and `$triggerInput` contains the message.

The errors are:

```
2017-05-25T22:24:38.484 Function started (Id=a0c37fdf-ed3c-473c-9c79-236d63531e7e)
2017-05-25T22:24:38.499 Function completed (Failure, Id=a0c37fdf-ed3c-473c-9c79-236d63531e7e, Duration=1ms)
2017-05-25T22:24:38.562 Exception while executing function: Functions.QueueTriggerPowerShell1. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: No value for named parameter 'file'.
```

Here's my PowerShell:

```
$inData = Get-Content $triggerInput
$inFile = Get-Content $inputFile

Write-Output "PowerShell script processed queue message '$inData'"
Write-Output "inFile: $inFile"
```

Here's function.json:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "triggerInput",
      "type": "queueTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "queueName": "samples-powershell-pdftoimage",
      "connection": "<storageaccount>_STORAGE"
    },
    {
      "type": "apiHubFile",
      "name": "inputFile",
      "path": "aapdftoimage/{file}",
      "connection": "onedriveforbusiness1_ONEDRIVEFORBUSINESS",
      "direction": "in"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

As I'm writing this, I think part of my confusion is over the Input and Output (not connected in my test) integrations of OneDrive for Business.

I know what `$triggerInput` is. It's the content of the message. But what is `$inputFile`? And where does `{file}` come from?

I thought maybe I would do the following but it too doesn't work (same errors):

```
$file = Get-Content $triggerInput
```

I thought this might define `$inputFile` as "aapdftoimage/$file" but it does nothing of the sort.

Needless to say, I'm at a standstill. Can anyone give me some guidance and straighten me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Henry Hamid Safi is correct.  Using C#, you can leverage the Binder object to dynamically name the file.

In your use-case, the only way to dynamically provide the name of the file is to pass it as a JSON object in your trigger payload.  Here is a sample setup that worked for me.

**function.json:**

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "triggerInput",
      "type": "queueTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "queueName": "samples-powershell",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage"
    },
    {
      "type": "apiHubFile",
      "name": "inputFile",
      "path": "aapdftoimage/{file}",
      "connection": "onedriveforbusiness_ONEDRIVEFORBUSINESS",
      "direction": "in"
    },
    {
      "type": "apiHubFile",
      "name": "outputFile",
      "path": "aapdftoimage/output_{file}",
      "connection": "onedriveforbusiness_ONEDRIVEFORBUSINESS",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

**run.ps1:**

```
$in = Get-Content $triggerInput
Write-Output "PowerShell script processed queue message '$in'"
Copy-Item $inputFile $outputFile
```

**Request body (if using Test pane in Portal) or Queue trigger payload:**

```
{
  "file":"ThreePages.pdf"
}
```

**Log entries:**

```
2017-05-26T22:27:53.984 Function started (Id=032c4469-8378-44ce-af9e-5a941afb0d82)
2017-05-26T22:27:54.875 PowerShell script processed queue message '{   "file":"ThreePages.pdf" }'
2017-05-26T22:27:54.891 Function completed (Success, Id=032c4469-8378-44ce-af9e-5a941afb0d82, Duration=899ms)
```

**OneDrive folder screen shot:**
[image]

Comment: Thank you! It's working! I think this is a lot of magic though. Lots of things happening automagically. I'd rather have to explicitly get the content, convert from JSON, assign to {file}, and then know what inputFile and outputFile.

Comment: Yes, your observation is correct.  Not being able to assign {file} inside your code is a known limitation at this stage. This applies to all languages supported in Azure Functions that are in experimental stage.  We have plans to address this in future releases but there is no ETA at the moment.

Comment: That's great. Glad to hear it.

Answer (score 1):

Working example

Function.json:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "triggerInput",
      "type": "queueTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "queueName": "test",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsDashboard"
    },
    {
      "type": "apiHubFile",
      "name": "inputFile",
      "path": "aapdftoimage/ThreePages.pdf",
      "connection": "onedrive_ONEDRIVE",
      "direction": "in"
    },
    {
      "type": "apiHubFile",
      "name": "outputFile",
      "path": "aapdftoimage/output_ThreePages.pdf",
      "connection": "onedrive_ONEDRIVE",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

run.ps1:

```
$in = Get-Content $triggerInput
Write-Output "PowerShell script processed queue message '$in'"

Copy-Item $inputFile $outputFile
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. In function.json you've specified the file to be moved. Doesn't this make it impossible to run dynamically?

Comment: Here is an example for doing something similar using C#: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43348985/dynamic-output-file-name-of-apihubfile-azure-function-binding-one-drive-drop-b