# How to name the file created in blob storage from a Powershell Azure Function?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-functions

Here is the **function.json** I have. The default for the `path` property is `{rand-guid}` which works.

I want name the file, I tried `{filename}` in the json and in the **run.ps1** tried setting `$env:filename` and `$filename`, it did not work.

Can this be done?

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myTimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 * 7 * * *"
    },
    {
      "type": "blob",
      "name": "outputBlob",
      "path": "outcontainer/{filename}",
      "connection": "testfunctionpsta0a5_STORAGE",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the output binding is not that simple. We need to pass a json object to the output binding to get the values.

Have a look at the examples on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings#advanced-binding-at-runtime-imperative-binding.

```
// function.json
{
    "name": "$return",
    "type": "blob",
    "direction": "out",
    "path": "output-container/{id}"
}

// C# example: use method return value for output binding
public static string Run(WorkItem input, TraceWriter log)
{
    string json = string.Format("{{ \"id\": \"{0}\" }}", input.Id);
    log.Info($"C# script processed queue message. Item={json}");
    return json;
}
```

Should be straightforward to do similar in Powershell.

Answer (score 0):

Could you pass the name of your file as part of your trigger payload? If yes, this SO [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44210957/6465830) may help.